# CSS Set something to align differently depending on screen resolution

Tags: css, width, screen, resolution, responsive

Here is the website i am developing...

http://camerabeanbags.co.uk/test/

This is responsive so if you take the web browser window and change the width you can see the website alter. If you look at the 'Your Cart' button on the top right of the green bar you can see it is aligned on the right. If you change the width of the web browser window it aligns to the left.

How can i change the width the web browser has to be before it aligns this to the left as i want it to do it only when there is no space for them to be next to each other. As on an iPad it aligns to the left but i want it to align it to the right. I have tried with the CSS @media but can't figure it out for this certain element.

Please can you help me with the CSS i need so it only aligns to the left at a certain screen width.

Thanks,

Harvey

Comment: Could you describe your problem in more detail? Because inside a media query you can place all css you want, so i dont understand the problem you run into.

Comment: I just need some CSS which will do the above. And some help with using the media query as i have only used it once before. If you open my the webpage http://camerabeanbags.co.uk/test/ and then reduce the width of the browser window you see the 'view cart' button goes over to the left even when there is space for it to fit on the right. I want to tell it to always align to the right unless below a certain width on resolution then it aligns to the left if you get me

Comment: If not i will get some screenshots later for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the CSS for your site, there is already a media query in place, which is what is causing the cart to move to the left. It looks like this:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #topbar .kad-topbar-left, #topbar .kad-topbar-left .topbarmenu {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

Above 767px, the style for those two elements is `float: left`.

If we delete that rule, so that the elements continue to float left, we can see that the cart will still fit in one row with the search up through 417px wide. So I would recommend simply revising the value in the media rule (using a rounder number):

```
@media (max-width: 420px) {
  #topbar .kad-topbar-left, #topbar .kad-topbar-left .topbarmenu {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: I will try and find the CSS file with this in it and if not I will just add it and mark it as important to see if it takes priority. You have any idea how I can use the developer tools in chrome to find out which file has this CSS?

Comment: Yes, right-click the little shopping cart and hit inspect. Move through the DOM in the Elements tab until you're on `div.topbarmenu.clearfix` (parent div of the shopping card `ul`). Narrow your screen down to under 767px, and the media query will show up on the side under the list of styles. It has a link to the exact path of the CSS file. You can do that for basically any style rule. This particular rule is coming from http://camerabeanbags.co.uk/test/wp-content/cache/wpfc-minified/5b7710815d7edcd601d0f9fc87e4bd73/1498383061index.css.

Comment: On my local test site anyway, not on the live one yet, thanks for the help :)

Comment: No problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
.kad-topbar-left{
    float: right !important;
}
```

This way it doesn't take full width on smaller window widths.

Comment: Hi, I have already tried this before and looks fine on a Tablet but on a mobile view it still aligns to the right, and the search bar is aligned to the left so it just doesn't look good, any other ideas?